# JavaScript doesn't detect indexOf -1 in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, indexof

I have a simple script that makes a fixture matching all values of an array against all.

```
const players = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const matches = [];

players.forEach(k => {
  players.forEach(j => {
    if(k !== j) {
      let z = [k, j]
      z.sort()
      const inArray = matches.indexOf(z) !== -1

      if(!inArray) matches.push(z)

      console.log(matches)
    }

  })
})
```

Although asking Javascript search for if `z` is in `matches` array, the result has duplicated items and returns this:

```
[ 'a', 'b' ]​​​​​​

​​​​​[ 'a', 'c' ]​​​​​​

​​​​​[ 'a', 'd' ]​​​​​​

​​​​​[ 'a', 'b' ]​​​​​​ --> duplicated item

​​​​​[ 'b', 'c' ]​​​​​​

​​​​​[ 'b', 'd' ]​​​​​​

​​​​​[ 'a', 'c' ]​​​​​​ --> duplicated item

​​​​​[ 'b', 'c' ]​​​​​​ --> duplicated item

​​​​​[ 'c', 'd' ]​​​​​​

​​​​​[ 'a', 'd' ]​​​​​​ --> duplicated item

​​​​​[ 'b', 'd' ]​​​​​​ --> duplicated item

​​​​​[ 'c', 'd' ]​​​​​​ --> duplicated item
```

How can avoid these duplicated items?

Comment: `indexOf()` doesn't take an array.

Comment: `indexOf` looks for equality, so only primitives will really work like that. ie: `"a" === "a" // true`, but `[] === [] // false`. Try looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Why are you calling `z.sort()`?

Comment: They are not duplicates. It's because you are sorting them (e.g. your 2nd ['a', 'b'] is actually ['b', 'a']

Comment: How about a solution that doesn't generate these duplicates in the first place? `players.forEach((v,i,a) => { while(++i < a.length) matches.push([v, a[i]]) })` or `Array.from(new Set(players)).forEach(...)` if players itself may contain duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you meant `if(!inArray) matches.push(z)`, right? Either way, `indexOf` will not compare the **values** of Arrays, but rather it is actually checking for referential equivalence, i.e. whether the *Array instances themselves are equal*.

In order to properly compare the **values** of your arrays, you'll probably want to write a helper function to use instead of `indexOf`. [Luckily, this answer explains how to do just that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/1122000)

[Additionally, here is a great article on MDN which breaks down various kinds of equality comparisons.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Answer (score 0):

If the array items will always be strings, you could do something a little hacky, but will get the job done

```
const players = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const matches = [];

players.forEach(k => {
  players.forEach(j => {
    if(k !== j) {
      let z = [k, j];

      z.sort()
      const inArray = matches.map(match=>match.join('')).indexOf(z.join('')) !== -1

      if(!inArray) matches.push(z)

      console.log(matches)
    }

  })
})
```

Basically you are turning the arrays into strings just before comparison which gives javascript a way to check to see if they are equal. Checking equality across array instances doesn't work and will return undesired results.